# How to call the getters and setters of inner class attributes in the TestApplication.java class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have a class AddressBook with the attributes long phoneNumber, Address tempAddress, Address permAddress where Address is the inner class of AddressBook. Its attributes are Name, City, Street, State. Both classes have getters and setters for all the attributes.

There is another class TestApplication where I need to test the working of the application by creating AddressBook object and print permanent, temporary address and phone number in the main method.

I could not figure out the way as to how to get to those Address class attributes into TestApplication, because of the confusing getters and setters of permAddress and tempAddress attributes.
[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG6jG.png)

What should be the right approach? Not able to implement the getters and setters of attributes tempAddress and permAddress of type Address.
So far this is the code of AddressBook.java and TestApplication.java.

```
    public class AddressBook{
    private long phoneNumber;
    private Address tempAddress;
    private Address permAddress;

    public void setPhoneNumber(long phoneNumber)
    {
        this.phoneNumber=phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setTempAddress(Address tempAddress)
    {
        this.tempAddress=tempAddress;
    }
    public void setPermAddress(Address permAddress)
    {
        this.permAddress=permAddress;
    }

    public long getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public Address getTempAddress()
    {
        return tempAddress;
    }
    public Address getPermAddress()
    {
        return permAddress;
    }

    class Address{
        private String name;
        private String street;
        private String city;
        private String state;

        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name=name;
        }
        public void setCity(String city)
        {
            this.city=city;
        }
        public void setStreet(String street)
        {
            this.street=street;
        }
        public void setState(String state)
        {
            this.state=state;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public String getStreet()
        {
            return street;
        }
        public String getCity()
        {
            return city;
        }
        public String getState()
        {
            return state;
        }
    } 
}



import java.util.*;
public class TestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the permanent address");
        System.out.println("Enter the house name");
        String hn=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the street");
        String stee=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the city");
        String city=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the state");
        String state=sc.nextLine();

        AddressBook a=new AddressBook();
        AddressBook.Address b=a.new Address();
        b.setName(hn);
        b.setStreet(stee);
        b.setCity(city);
        b.setState(state);

        System.out.println("Permanent address");
        AddressBook ad=new AddressBook();
        System.out.println("House name:"+ad.getPermAddress().getName());
        System.out.println("Street:"+ad.getPermAddress().getStreet());
        System.out.println("City:"+ad.getPermAddress().getCity());
        System.out.println("State:"+ad.getPermAddress().getState());

        System.out.println("Enter the temporary address");
        System.out.println("Enter the house name");
        String house=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the street");
        String street1=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the city");
        String city1=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the state");
        String state1=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the phone number");
        long ph=sc.nextLong();


        System.out.println("Temporary address");
        System.out.println("House name:"+ad.getTempAddress().getName());
        System.out.println("Street:"+ad.getTempAddress().getStreet());
        System.out.println("City"+ad.getTempAddress().getCity());
        System.out.println("State:"+ad.getTempAddress().getState());


        ad.setPhoneNumber(ph);
        System.out.println("Phone number"+ad.getPhoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details about your code. Just saying that it's confusing doesn't give us a lot of information

Comment: I have added the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

So getters and setters are non-static methods (in most cases). What this means is that you will have to instantiate the object and then call the methods. So what you have to do is create Address instance `Address  a = new Address (...);` and then you can use the instance to call your getters and setters, i.e. `a.getZipCode();` etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `sc.next()` instead of `sc.nextLine()` while taking the user input.

Answer (score -1):

Because the inner class isn't public you need to get the Adress attributes like:
gettempAdresse().getName();

First you return an object of the type Adresse with "gettempAdresse()" and then you call the "getName()" method of this object which returns the name.

Edit:

You need to add `constructors` to each class first.

```
public AddressBook() {
        tempAddress = new Address();
        permAddress = new Address();
    }

public Address(String name, String street, String city, String state) {
        this.name = name;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
}

public Address() {
    this("", "", "", "");
}
```

After this, you can create a instence of AddressBook and use the getters and setters like this:

```
AddressBook addressBook = new AddressBook();                    //create instence of AddressBook

addressBook.setPermAddress(addressBook.new Address());          //set permAddress to a new Address
addressBook.getPermAddress().setName("name of permAddress");    //set name of permAddress
```

Comment: How to set first the values in settempAddress()?